# inequalities like x^{p/q}>3x^{r/t}

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, radicals

I don't remember how to resolve in the classical way an equation like

$$x^{4/5}>3x^{1/2}$$
I think to do:
$$x^{4/5}>3x^{1/2} \iff \frac{x^{4/5}}{x^{1/2}}>3 \iff x^{3/10}>3 $$
(obviously for $x^{1/2}\neq 0$)
 but I'm not sure is the correct way...

Comment: The $\iff$ only applies if both sides of the inequality are positive

Answer (score 1):

If u multiply or divide the unknown in an inequality it might change depending on x, for a proper way x^4/5 - 3x½ >0 , then take common x½ and you get two inequalities and take the intersection of both the answers, if you do so u will see you might have missed a set of answer.